# Using lens, cosmosOf, uniplate, and the State monad to extract info about an AST

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have [the following code](https://github.com/wincent/docvim/blob/1614c718e7ca99bf20a8c487df76558f55ef2b77/lib/Docvim/Visitor/Section.hs) that traverses [an AST](https://github.com/wincent/docvim/blob/1614c718e7ca99bf20a8c487df76558f55ef2b77/lib/Docvim/AST.hs) using [`cosmosOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:cosmosOf) and [`uniplate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Data-Data-Lens.html#v:uniplate) looking for nodes of a certain type. For any that it finds, it sets a `Bool` flag in a record that is propagated using a `State` monad with the help of [the `lens` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14).

This all works, but feels pretty heavy-handed. It feels like lenses, the `State` monad, and possibly `cosmosOf`/`uniplate` may all be overkill here. Is there a better or more idiomatic way to do this?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Docvim.Visitor.Section (getSectionInfo) where

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Data.Lens (uniplate)
import Docvim.AST

data SectionInfo = SectionInfo { _hasCommand :: Bool
                               , _hasCommands :: Bool
                               , _hasFunction :: Bool
                               , _hasFunctions :: Bool
                               , _hasMapping :: Bool
                               , _hasMappings :: Bool
                               , _hasOption :: Bool
                               , _hasOptions :: Bool
                               } deriving (Show)

type Env = State SectionInfo

makeLenses ''SectionInfo

defaultSectionInfo :: SectionInfo
defaultSectionInfo = SectionInfo { _hasCommand = False
                                 , _hasCommands = False
                                 , _hasFunction = False
                                 , _hasFunctions = False
                                 , _hasMapping = False
                                 , _hasMappings = False
                                 , _hasOption = False
                                 , _hasOptions = False
                                 }

getSectionInfo :: Node -> SectionInfo
getSectionInfo n = execState (mapMOf_ (cosmosOf uniplate) check n) defaultSectionInfo
  where
    check (CommandAnnotation {}) = hasCommand .= True
    check CommandsAnnotation     = hasCommands .= True
    check (FunctionAnnotation _) = hasFunction .= True
    check FunctionsAnnotation    = hasFunctions .= True
    check (MappingAnnotation _)  = hasMapping .= True
    check MappingsAnnotation     = hasMappings .= True
    check (OptionAnnotation {})  = hasOption .= True
    check OptionsAnnotation      = hasOptions .= True
    check _                      = modify id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do can be accomplished by [`para`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate-1.6.12/docs/Data-Generics-Uniplate.html#v:para) from the Uniplate module.

Basically `para` aggregates information collected from a node and its children and passed it up to the node's parent for further aggregation.

Here's a simplified version of your example - we determine whether or not a Node contains CommandAnnotation and/or FunctionAnnotation nodes

```
import Data.Monoid
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import qualified Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data as Uniplate
import Data.Data

...

data HasSection = HasCommandAnnotation | HasFunction | HasOther
  deriving (Show,Read,Enum,Bounded,Ord,Eq)

toHas :: Node -> HasSection  
toHas (CommandAnnotation {})   = HasCommandAnnotation
toHas (FunctionsAnnotation {}) = HasFunction
toHas _                        = HasOther

getSectionInfo :: Node -> Set.Set HasSection
getSectionInfo n = Uniplate.para visit n
  where visit n res = Set.singleton (toHas n) <> mconcat res
```

The [README.md](https://github.com/ndmitchell/uniplate) at the uniplate github repo has a good overview of the library with examples.

For better efficiency you could use the [`bitset`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bitset) package for the sets.

Comment: There is also a [para](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:para) for `Plated`, the equivalent of `Uniplate` in the lens package.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are asking about how best to implement the `walk` function for your custom tree. This can be done using simple recursion, which doesn't depend on any libraries. On the other hand, depending on the size of your ADTs it's a lot more typing. But the consumers of your library will be thankful if they don't have to install lenses etc.

For a good example, see [pandoc's walk functions](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/Text/Pandoc/Walk.hs) to traverse its [AST](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs#L211):

- `walk  :: (a -> a) -> b -> b` simply modifies the tree, while
- `walkM :: (Monad m, Functor m) => (a -> m a) -> b -> m b` is monadic, so additionally you can for example keep state around, like the boolean values you asked about. There's nothing wrong with that and the state monad was in fact built for cases like this.